# Java Letter Distance?

Tags: java

Is there a way to find the distance of letters in Java?

What I mean is for example:

```
A -> C = 3 (as A, B, C)
B -> G = 6 (as B, C, D, E, F, G)
R -> Z = 9 (as R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z)
```

(I am looking for distance that is inclusive of the first letter)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For strings containing a single character:

```
String s1 = "A";
String s2 = "c";

int result = ((int)s2.toLowerCase().charAt(0) - (int)s1.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) + 1;
```

If you are working with just characters (no strings), then Java's `Character` class has a static `toLowerCase()` method.

**Edit**

For the case where the result may be negative ('A' - 'C'):

```
result = Math.abs(result);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
int diff = Character.toLowerCase('C') - Character.toLowerCase('A');
```

This works, because each `char` is associated with an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) value. 'C' has the value 67 and 'A' is 65, thus `'C' - 'A'` == `67 - 65`. Note that this only works as long as all of the characters are uppercase or all characters are lowercase.

Comment: Just be sure the asker knows this will give a different result if he mixes upper and lower case.  +1

Comment: Just a note, remember that lowercase and uppercase have different values, if you dont care about case convert all to upper or lowercase first then compare.

Comment: You should add a `+1`, because the OP wants to count all letters including the ones given.

Comment: Edited to incorporate everyone's comments.

Comment: `Character.toLowerCase()` is always an option.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  I added it in.

Comment: Since `char`s in Java are not ASCII but Unicode, maybe it would be nice to use that term. Yes, ASCII agrees with Unicode in the narrow range it covers, but this will also work for the much wider Unicode range with no change.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting ASCII code and UNICODE code points should work most of the time.

For an encoding-independent solution, you can use this snippet: this will work even if you use some [really archaic encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) <strike>that were around when dinosaurs roamed the Earth</strike>.

```
String all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int diff = all.indexOf('Y')-all.indexOf('B')+1;
```

Comment: Interesting thought!  I never would have considered that.  Are there times when people will voluntarily use those encodings today?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Oh, not voluntarily, no. For big money, perhaps, but not for the fun of it or anything. I'm not even sure if Java on mainframes uses EBCDIC.

Comment: The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2): "The integral types are [...], and `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1)".

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution:

```
public static int countLetters(char a, char b)
{
    return Math.abs(Character.toLowerCase(a) - Character.toLowerCase(b)) + 1;
}
```

```
System.out.println(countLetters('a', 'B'));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `char` variables can actually be treated as `int`.  The range of a `char` variable is 0 through 65,535 (inclusive), with each number corresponding to a different Unicode character.

As such, you can simply perform mathematical operations directly on the characters to achieve the desired results.  To convert your given example:

```
System.out.println(('C'-'A') + 1);
> 3
System.out.println(('G'-'B') + 1);
> 6
System.out.println(('Z'-'R') + 1);
> 9
```

We must add one in order to make the distance inclusive.

It's important to note that whether the characters are capital or lower case will affect the outcome because they have different Unicode values.  For instance, the following operations yields an unintended result:

```
System.out.println(('c'-'A') + 1);
> 35
```

So if you want the distance between two letters completely independent of case, be sure to add some case checking in between the input and your mathematical operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

`System.out.println('C' - 'A' + 1);`